# Adding drop-shadow to map layer

Tags: mapbox, shadow, dropshadow

I'm a UI Designer, and my client will use mapbox for his website. I'm working on a custom style where I want to make the whole map white with a drop-shadow.

I know only basics for now, so there's my question. **How can I add a drop-shadow for 'land' layer?** I just want to know if it's possible and it would be awesome to know the solution.

Thanks,
Robert

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about a style based on Mapbox Streets, then no, it's not possible, because there is actually no "land" layer. Instead, there are ocean layers, and land is just the background.

In general, "drop shadows" aren't really something you can easily do in Mapbox GL, although there are ways to kind of fake it with properties such as [fill-translate](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/layers/#paint-fill-fill-translate).